# Split data within one column into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which one of the columns contains data regarding (lat and lng).
I would like to write an SQL script that split the column into two columns one for lat and the other for LNG.

Note the lat and Lng are split by a comma.

The table looks like below

````
id     pid      code    class   sclass         name     coordinates
24079   4273753 5122    Roads   residential Apoteksgatan    [
[
[
58.26574,
12.9477909
],
[
58.2643948,
12.9490654
],
[
58.2640484,
12.9494174
],
[
58.2638978,
12.9498716
],
[
58.2637401,
12.9505464
],
[
58.2634622,
12.9518316
]
]
]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are SQL Server version 2016 or later you can use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
    (
        [id] INT
      , [pid] BIGINT
      , [code] INT
      , [class] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [sclass] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [name] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [coordinates] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [id]
                        , [pid]
                        , [code]
                        , [class]
                        , [sclass]
                        , [name]
                        , [coordinates]
                      )
VALUES ( 24079
       , 4273753
       , 5122
       , 'Roads'
       , 'residential'
       , 'Apoteksgatan'
       , '[ [ [ 58.26574, 12.9477909 ], [ 58.2643948, 12.9490654 ], [ 58.2640484, 12.9494174 ], [ 58.2638978, 12.9498716 ], [ 58.2637401, 12.9505464 ], [ 58.2634622, 12.9518316 ] ] ]' );

SELECT      [a].[id]
          , [d].[Key]
          , [d].[Value]
FROM        @testdata [a]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([a].[coordinates]) [b]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([b].[Value]) [c]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([c].[Value]) [d];
```

Which gives you the following results

```
id          Key Value
----------- --- -----------
24079       0   58.26574
24079       1   12.9477909
24079       0   58.2643948
24079       1   12.9490654
24079       0   58.2640484
24079       1   12.9494174
24079       0   58.2638978
24079       1   12.9498716
24079       0   58.2637401
24079       1   12.9505464
24079       0   58.2634622
24079       1   12.9518316
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not an ideal data structure.  I would reccomend at a minimum to put the data in XML or JSON format as MS SQL has tools for working inside that kind of dense data in a single tuple (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).  More perfectly, you would create a child table joined to the id filed (if it is the Primary Key) and list all of the lat/longs in seperate columns.  A query for that becomes trivial.

To accomplish what you want with what you have, the dirty answer is to use the LIKE clause.  So if I wanted to fins a specific set of coordinates:

```
WHERE     coordinates LIKE '%[58.2637401,%'
      AND coordinates LIKE '%,12.9505464]%'
```

I think you will have to play with the pattern match due to the CR/LFs in the text.  If you can't get that to work, look at the TRIM command to strip them out.